# Identify duplicates within columns using sql (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates, having-clause

I have the following dataset:

```
FLD_NB|RGN_CD
1     |NC
2     |SC
1     |MA
3     |GA
3     |MA
```

I am trying to identify all records which are available in more than 1 `RGN_CD`, so e.g. the scenario above, `FLD_NB=1` is available in both `RGN_CD='NC'` and `RGN_CD='MA'`

What might be the best way to identify the rows which has multiple instances of `FLD_NB` across `RGN_CD`?

Comment: Please add example data and expected results...

Comment: What about `FLD_NB=3` , which should also be one of such candidate right ?

Comment: Please provide an example of required results

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select fld_nb
from mytable
group by fld_nb
having count(*) > 1
```

This gives you all `fld_nb`s that appear more than once. Or, if you want `fld_nb`s that have more than one *distinct* `rgn_cd`, you can change the having clause to:

```
having count(distinct rgn_cd) > 1
```

Comment: i think this will work for what I am specifically looking for - i reduced the number of columns from the resultset and then I think I could get the right result using this query - I am still checking but so far looks good - thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need:

```sql
select *
from (
     select t.*
           ,count(*)over(partition by FLD_NB) cnt
     from t
     )
where cnt>1;
```

Full tests case with results:

```sql
with t (FLD_NB,RGN_CD) as (
select 1, 'NC' from dual union all
select 2, 'SC' from dual union all
select 1, 'MA' from dual union all
select 3, 'GA' from dual union all
select 3, 'MA' from dual 
)
select *
from (
     select t.*
           ,count(*)over(partition by FLD_NB) cnt
     from t
     )
where cnt>1;
```

Results:

```sql
    FLD_NB RG        CNT
---------- -- ----------
         1 NC          2
         1 MA          2
         3 MA          2
         3 GA          2
```

In case if you need to count just distinct values:

```sql
select *
from (
     select t.*
           ,count(distinct RGN_CD)over(partition by FLD_NB) cnt
     from t
     )
where cnt>1;
```

Comment: yes, that is the reultset I am expecting, however this table as usual has plenty of other columns along with these two main columns on which I have to identify the duplicates - i checked the sql by changing the column names to the main 2 columns however the resultset is still throwing more rows that I did not want to see ...e.g. if I have FLD_NB=22 and it has 7 rows with same RGN_CD=NA still those rows are returned which I don't want coz that FLD_NM=22 isn't repeating in any other RGN_CD

Comment: @sourabhbhattacharya ah, ok, so just change `count(*)over` to `count(distinct RGN_CD) over`

Comment: Great, so please mark the answer as a correct id it works for you